# How to make a RCP-Plugin standalone

Tags: java, swt, rcp, equinox

I've started a project as a RCP Plugin.
Now I need it as Standalone.

I've tried to add a feature project and a product file but I think that it doesn't work that way because I make contributions to the UI (I'm extending ViewPart) - is it even possible to make this plugin standalone? If yes, can tell me someone detailed how or give me a good resource?

Comment: Adding the feature and product should do the trick. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I've solved it with a little trick - i post the solution when I have more time

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the core logic from the presentation logic and provide an interface to abstract the UI?

Then create a SWT implementation to satisfy the plug-in requirements and any other UI's you need.